# unrecognized selector sent to instance в swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class MainTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{  

     var name: [Notes] = [Notes(nameText: "Первая заметка", mainText: "Это ее текст"),
                         Notes(nameText: "Вторая заметка", mainText: "Это ее текст"),
                         Notes(nameText: "Третья заметка", mainText: "Это ее текст")]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lessImage", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellLessImage
        cell.nameText.text = name[indexPath.row].nameText
        cell.mainText.text = name[indexPath.row].mainText
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return name.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 66
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
}
```

> myProgram.MainViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc9d050b440

Comment: у вас делегат неправильно указан - должен быть не MainViewController а MainTableView (либо наоборот, методы написаны не в том классе, в зависимости от желаемой бизнес логики)

Comment: *В данном случае - датасорс, но и делегат тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас датасорс неправильно указан - должен быть не MainViewController а MainTableView (либо наоборот, методы написаны не в том классе, в зависимости от желаемой бизнес логики)